# Monitor changes to content of html binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to bind HTML to a div element, edit the content of that div with some sort of edit in place editor, click a save button and retrieve the new content, but I have been unsuccessful.

The view looks like this:

```html
<div id="content" data-bind="html: content"></div>
<button data-bind="click: function(){ save() }">Save</button>
```

With this Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    content: ko.observable("<h3>Test</h3>"),
    save: function(){
        console.log(ko.toJSON(viewModel));    
    }
}

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $("#content").html("<h4>Test</h4>");
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById('content'));
});
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcreamer898/rXLQK/2/).

When I click save the console still says `<h3>Test</h3>`.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: could you explain what are you intending to do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The html binding does not setup any event handlers to catch changes, as it is normally placed on elements that are not editable.

Here is a sample of using the `contenteditable` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JksKx/ (from this thread).

If you are looking to integrate with an editor like `TinyMCE`, then here is a sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GwkRQ/  (from this thread).