# Update knockoutjs viewmodel when dom text changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need the underling data to be updated when the bound table cell text is updated.

What do I need to do to make the update work?

example : http://jsfiddle.net/2hdRp/1/

Comment: Why do you update cell text instead of updating underlying data directly? The whole point of knockout.js is that you can work with your view model and don't worry about updating the UI - the framework will take care about it for you. If later you want to change presentation (switch from tables to div, for instance), you don't have to change any code, just change html and set up bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a bad question with a bad example. I wanted to know how to update the ViewModel whenever when the dom changes in cases where there is no input control, like `contenteditable`, or dynamic controls that update the dom.

Anyway, I like AlfeG's answer and this similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987132/knockoutjs-html-binding).

But, I opted for using the new [dataFor](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) helper function. Using that, I can easily update the underlying ViewModel.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2hdRp/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is not already implemented in KnockoutJs framework.

This is my custom bindings for You question:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.textValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
         // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 

        $(element).change(function(){
            value($(this).text());
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 
        $(element).text(valueUnwrapped);
    }
};
```

Binding will look like:

```html
<td id="idCell" data-bind="textValue: Car.id, valueUpdate: 'change'"
    class="header"></td>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlfeG/dNtNb/

Answer (score 1):

You should change the underlying value, the observable, instead of updating the DOM.